# Toggle background color

Tags: jquery

Here I changed the navbar **background color** on click **LINK** (DD One or DD Two) from white to black, I need when unclick **LINK** (DD One or DD Two) navbar should revert to white background.

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/7wbvedph/15/)**

```
// Navigation dropdown start

  $(".navbar-header .dropdown .nav-link").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".navbar-header").addClass("navbar-selected");
  });

  $(document).click(function(event){
    $(".navbar-header").removeClass("navbar-selected");
  });

  // Navigation dropdown end
```

[image]

I need to do like this - https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/1x56droe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the [dropdown events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#events) from bootstrap to add or remove the class when the menu opens or closes, like so:

```
$(".navbar-header").on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("navbar-selected");
});

$(".navbar-header").on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("navbar-selected");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, msg.
This is I wanted. Thanks a lot.
Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by saving the previous target and based on that add/remove the `navbar-selected` class like:

```
let previousTarget = null;
$(".navbar-header .dropdown .nav-link").click(function(e) {
  if (this !== previousTarget) {
    $(this).closest(".navbar-header").addClass("navbar-selected");
    previousTarget = this;
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".navbar-header.navbar-selected").removeClass("navbar-selected");
    previousTarget = null;
  }  
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sm324bxo/)

Comment: Hi Palash, thank you for response, I tried 'toggleClass' but, when I click DD-One and then click DD-Two, then the background makes matter.

Comment: You mean to say when you click DD-One and then click it again, it is working fine. But when you click DD-One and then click DD-Two the navbar-selected class should still remain there and only be removed when DD-Two is clicked again?

Comment: YES, EXACTLY THIS :)

Answer (score 0):

I built upon palash's response to account for this. You just add and remove the class based on whether or not it has the class `navbar-active` on it. I hope this is the use case you're looking for. Let me know

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/tqou8d4x/6/)

```
// Navigation dropdown start

  $(".navbar-header .dropdown .nav-link").click(function(e){
  var header = $(this).closest(".navbar-header");
    if (header.classList.has("navbar-selected"))
    {
        header.classList.remove("navbar-selected");
    } else
    {
        header.classList.add("navbar-selected");
    }
  });
```